# DB2 COALESCE - notable impact on query time execution

Tags: sql, performance, db2, prepared-statement, coalesce

I've noted that using COALESCE (in my case) to avoid possible NULL value in prepared statement causes a decrease in performance of DB query time execution. Can someone explain me what is the root cause and how can I overcome that issue? Queries samples below:

**QUERY 1 (execution time 3 s):**

```
SELECT TABLE_A.Y, TABLE_B.X
FROM ...
WHERE Z = ? AND TABLE_A.ABC = ? AND
     TABLE_A.QWERTY = ? AND TABLE_A.Q = TABLE_B.Q;
```

**QUERY 2 (execution time 210 s):**

```
SELECT TABLE_A.Y, TABLE_B.X
FROM ...
WHERE Z = ? AND (
  (COALESCE(?,'')='') OR 
  (TABLE_A.ABC = ? AND TABLE_A.QWERTY = ? AND TABLE_A.Q = TABLE_B.Q)
);
```

The only difference is using (COALESCE(?,'')='').

Comment: Your queries are lacking a `FROM` clause.  But the answer to your question is "Yes": Changing the `WHERE` clause can and does affect how a query is optimized.

Comment: I would venture to guess that the main reason is the added `OR` rather than  `COALESCE()`. The query optimizer has no way of knowing the selectivity of `COALESCE(?,'')='')`. The answer to your "why" would be evident after comparing the query plans.

Comment: add the explain output for both queries, so that we can take an educated guess. It seems that the OR is the cause for the trouble.

Comment: Basically i would like to retrieve some data from DB. Assuming that input for TABLE_A.ABC can be null I'm going to maintain Prepared Statement by using COALESCE. Do you can find other way?
i.e.
(COALESCE(valueForTABLE_A.ABC,'')='') OR 
  (TABLE_A.ABC = valueForTABLE_A.ABC AND TABLE_A.QWERTY = ? AND TABLE_A.Q = TABLE_B.Q)

Answer (score 0):

The bigger problem I see is that `QUERY 1` has `3` placeholders whereas `QUERY 2` has `4` placeholders.

I think what you're trying to do is that you want to make your placeholders  optional.

A simple way to do this is to fix QUERY 1 as follows

```
SELECT TABLE_A.Y, TABLE_B.X
FROM TABLE_A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.Q = TABLE_B.Q;
WHERE Z = ? 
  AND TABLE_A.ABC = COALESCE(?,TABLE_A.ABC) 
  AND TABLE_A.QWERTY = COALESCE(?,TABLE_A.QWERTY)
```

Comment: Actually your proposition would be fine if column ABC from table TABLE_A would be mandatory one in Data Base, but it isn't. Using your approach, in case when placeholder for column ABC will be null achieved result won't be correct. Comparing column to itself, gives in result only records with positive (NOT NULL) value, while it should return all records (including NULL ones). That is why (COALESCE(?,'')='') is in use.
I'm just wondering if there is a solution to replace it with some construction which would not cause performance issues, maintaining Prepared Statement at the same time.

Comment: The important thing to remember is to always have an un-altered column value.  If you apply functions to a column, the index cannot be used == slower.